# delete/approve comment

Tags: 7, comments

How can the administrator delete an "impolite" comment and approve comments before publishing?

Globally speaking, what is the best management of the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set permissions for users - `Skip comment approval` in `admin/people/permissions/list#module-comment`(in drupal 7). After as admin you can manage your comments here - `admin/content/comment` you can approve comments, delete them or unpublish.